# JPQL Resolve Concat TO NULL

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I need help, I'm working With Eclipse-Link 2.4 (the newer), well
I have some JPQL functions with CONCAT string function and I am usin the Instruccion

```
SELECT NEW test.Routing(r.idOperacion, CONCAT(r.reference, 'Test') ) FROM Routing r;
```

It is more complex but I have made the JPQL a little short, this is the problem

Is resolving `CONCAT(r.reference, 'Test')` as a `Boolean` and said that there is no constructor like `Routing(Strnig, Boolean)` because there is not, only take 2 strings, this happens since I have upgrade my eclipselink from glassfish.

Answer (score 3):

You have spotted bug in EclipseLink 2.4. Query is syntactically correct JQPL query and it works for example in EclipseLink 2.3.3.

Workaround is to call CONCAT database function with using [FUNC](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.1.0/JPAQueryEnhancements#FUNC):

```
SELECT NEW test.Routing(r.idOperacion, FUNC('CONCAT', r.reference, 'Test') ) 
FROM Routing r;
```

What else you can possibly do is to file bug and rollback to version 2.3.3, if features introduced in 2.4 are not needed.